# calculating the byte usage of a plain number instance

Tags: java, numbers, primitive-types

I am writing a custom file format where I want to parse a certain region of the file into a map which takes strings as keys and java.lang.number instances (e.g. int, long) as values. Is there any way to access the byte usage of the values without having to determine their class type first? I mean all subclasses of Number have a static variable called "BYTES" referencing the actual number of bytes they use.
I want to do something like this:

`byte b = ((Number)map.get("key")).BYTES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the BYTES constant using reflection:

```
Number number = map.get("key");
int numberOfBytes = number.getClass().getDeclaredField("BYTES").getInt(number);
```

Comment: This just came to me... My original answer was wrong. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is long hand

```
byte b = 0;
Number n = (Number)map.get("key");
if (n instanceof Integer) {
  b = 4;
}
else if (n instanceof Byte) {
  b = 1;
}
else if ...
```

David SN posted a solution using reflection which may work out better for you

Comment: Hmm I thought there was another way around. Anyways, thanks!